# C array size via gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I know you can print an array in gdb , e.g.

```
(gdb) p *array@10
```

Is there a gdb command that can tell you its length, e.g. a handy shortcut to typing something like:

```
(gdb) p sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)
```

In the case where the array has been defined at compile time and you want to check it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may use `ptype` to know the type of a symbol.

For `int array[5]`,

```
(gdb) ptype array
type = int [5]
```

Answer (score 13):

If it's actually defined as an array, e.g.

```
int array[5];
```

Then yes, you can use what you wrote, although a better and more general way is:

```
(gdb) p sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)
```

This doesn't assume the type of the array.

If the variable is defined as a pointer, then no.

Comment: good point, that is more generic - i thought there may be some gdb shortcut for that? or possibly you can define your own somehow?

Comment: @Hiett Well, if you just print the array, it'll print all the values. Beyond that, I don't know.