# Extend stl-views.gdb with parray

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, gdb

I want to extend the [stl-views.gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=stl-views-1.0.3.gdb) with parray

How can I determine the size (N) of std::array in gdb?

```
#
# std::array<>
#

define parray
  if $argc == 0
    help parray
  else
    set $size = ???
..
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try using `set $size = $arg0.size()`.

I have tested with the following code (where `.size()` is not used explicitly used).

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 3> arr {1,2,3};
    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Then the following defined worked

```
define parray
  if $argc == 0
    help parray
  else
    set $size = $arg0.size()
    print($size)
end
```

both with a running process or without a running process (debugging from a core file).

If calling `.size()` does not work for some reason then we need to see which internal variables of the array we can use. Using `p /r arr` we can see the `arr` variable without any pretty-printing. This shows something like

```
$5 = {
  _M_elems =     {[0] = 1,
    [1] = 2,
    [2] = 3}
}
```

in my machine (code was compiled with gcc 10), but it might be implementation-dependent. We can then try to get the size from `_M_elems`.

We can then try using the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808448/c-array-size-via-gdb) to get the size. That is, using something such as

```
set $size = sizeof($arg0._M_elems) / sizeof(*$arg0._M_elems)
```

The gdb define code becomes

```
define parray
  if $argc == 0
    help parray
  else
    set $size = sizeof($arg0._M_elems) / sizeof(*$arg0._M_elems)
    print($size)
end
```

Comment: Sorry, as a result I get 'Cannot evaluate function -- may be inlined' (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374088)

Comment: You can only call functions with an existing running process and if they are included in the binary (if they were not discarded by the linker or inlined by the compiler, for instance). However, gdb allows you to write xmethods, which are python implementations for C++ methods that are used when the C++ method is not available. Also, gdb already has xmethods for many methods in the standard library, including the `size()` method of many containers. I have tested using `.size` like this and it worked **even when debugging from a core file**.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an approach that works even if you can't use `.size()`.